# Cloud Mobile Stratus C5 Elite stuck in boot loop due to missing/incompatible ROM

Tags: boot-loop, rom

I got a phone Cloud Mobile Stratus C5 Elite stuck in boot loop after 2 days. I'm sure it's the ROM that is missing or incompatible and I have no clue which one is supported. It's running Android 11 Go edition, 16 GB, dual-SIM.

It would be very appreciated if someone could help or even if they could point me in the direction to even find out.

Comment: ROM missing or incompatible is possible if bootloader was unlocked and the user forced so. If that is the case flash proper ROM from fastboot

Comment: http://www.deviceinfohw.ru/devices/item.php?item=565366

Comment: Thank you very much on your help but still can't figure this out I go to recovery n the partition cache is missing when resetting it factory it's says open failed  metadata/it's  no such file or directory an cause the bootloop my PC won't recognize it I plug it up.    any advice ?

Comment: please add info to your question, not comments. type error messages exactly.

Comment: in recovery mode there is maybe option reboot to bootloader. install fastboot drivers and check *'fastboot devices'* is working. try to create partition *'fastboot format:ext4 cache'*

Comment: [fastboot](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) + [drivers](https://superuser.com/a/1674819/878585)